# Spark : Key not found

Tags: apache-spark-sql, partition

I am trying to insert into hive table from spark using following syntax.

```
tranl1.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("t_date").insertInto("tran_spark_part")
```

Note : `tranl1` is DF, I had created it for loading data from oracle.

```
val tranl1 = sqlContext.load("jdbc", Map("url" -> "jdbc:oracle:thin:userid/pwd@localhost:portid","dbtable" -> "(select a.*,to_char(to_date(trunc(txn_date,'DD'),'dd-MM-yy')) as t_date from table a  WHERE TXN_DATE >= TRUNC(sysdate,'DD'))"))
```

my table in hive :

> create table tran_spark_part(id string,amount string,creditaccount
>   string,creditbankname string,creditvpa string,customerid
>   string,debitaccount string,debitbankname string,debitvpa string,irc
>   string,refid string,remarks string,rrn string,status string,txn_date
>   string,txnid string,type string,expiry_date string,approvalnum
>   string,msgid string,seqno string,upirc string,reversal string,trantype
>   string) partitioned by (date1 string);

However when i run

```
tranl1.write.mode("overwrite").partitionBy("t_date").insertInto("tran_spark_part")
```

it gives error :

```
java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: date1
```

Please help me what I am missing or doing wrong?

Comment: Do you got any solution for same ?